# Check if statement true for all list items

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following dictionary:

```
    dictionary = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0, 'D':0}
```

I would like to check if all the values stored by the dictionary keys are zero and then execute some code. What I had in mind is something like:

```
    if (dictionary[k] == 0 for all k in dictionary.keys()):
        # do something
```

What I am currently doing is:

```
  if (dictionary['A'] == 0 and dictionary['B'] == 0 and dictionary['C'] == 0 and dictionary['D'] == 0):
      # do something
```

This seems very inefficient if my dictionary grows larger. Is there any way I could check a condition for all keys and demand all of them to be simultaneously true?

Comment: `set(dictionary.values()) == {0}`

Comment: `all(v == 0 for v in dictionary.values())`?

Comment: ```not any(dictionary.values())```?

Comment: @dsvp Nice and short, but definitely more confusing to the reader.

Comment: `all(dictionary.values())`-- however, i prefer my original suggest or that of deceze, since they explicitly check for `0` not relying on ints or truithiness

Comment: @dsvp9xyjsqmfvi8p, @Chris_Rands , will fail @ `{'A':0, 'B':False}`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, not very short but nice and readable

```py
def check(dictionary):
    for value in dictionary.values():
        if value != 0:
            return False
    return True
if check({'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0, 'D':0}):
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this function that can make your code look clean and you can change params as you wish.

```
# function that return True if all your dictionary values are equal to 0 and false if any value has a different value

def check(dictionary, val): 
    for key in dictionary:
        if dictionary[key]!= val: 
            return False 
    return True

if check(dictionary,0):
 #do something
```